# React Hide/Show Menu on Successful Login and Passing Information from one Component to a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Total Newbie in React and most of my learning is done through experimentation.

I have the following components:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Libraries and Utilities
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import Layout from './components/layout/Layout';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Login from './components/login/Login';

class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename='/myapp>
                <Layout>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                        <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
                    </Switch>
                </Layout>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavMenu from '../navigation/NavMenu';

class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className="main layout">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Layout;
```

**NavMenu.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import logo from '../../assets/logo.svg';

class navigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <img src={logo} width="250" height="70" alt="" />
                    </a>

                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item" to={'/'}>
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="navbar-brand" activeClassName='active' to='/'>Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" to={'/admin1'}>
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="navbar-brand" activeClassName='active' to='/admin1'>Admin 1</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" to={'/admin2'}>
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="navbar-brand" activeClassName='active' to='/admin1'>Admin 2</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="navbar-brand" activeClassName='active' to='/login'>
                                    <i className="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    };
};

export default navigation;
```

**Login .js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            loginModel: {
                UserName: '',
                Password: ''
            }
        }

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
        const name = target.name

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            loginModel: {
                ...prevState.loginModel,
                [name]: value
            }
        }))
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        // At This Stage, I perform an API Call (via axios) and I get the Response Data.
        const url = 'some  url'
                axios.post(url, this.state.loginModel).then((response) => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        // Get token from response to be used in authenticated api calls.
                        const responseData = response.data
                        let authToken = responseData.token
                        console.log('authToken', authToken)

                        swal({
                            title: "My Application",
                            text: "Logon Successful.",
                            icon: "success"
                        }).then((value) => {
                            // Go to the Admin Home.
                            const path = '/admin'
                            this.props.history.push(path);
                        })
                    }
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err.response)
                        const msg = err.response.data.message
                        const icon = err.response.data.icon
                    swal({
                        title: "My Application",
                        text: msg,
                        icon: icon
                    })
                })
        )

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (

            <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <h3>Sign In</h3>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" autoComplete="off" 
                        id="input-username" name="UserName"
                        value={this.state.loginModel.UserName}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        placeholder="Enter Username" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" autoComplete="off"
                        id="input-password" name="Password"
                        value={this.state.loginModel.Password}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        placeholder="Enter Password" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
            </form>
            
        )
    }
}

export default login;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const home = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="fill">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body flex-fill">
                                <h5 className="card-title">Info 1</h5>
                                <p className="card-text">
                                    Details about Info 1
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-footer">
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="btn btn-primary btn-block" to='/info1'>Start</NavLink>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body flex-fill">
                                <h5 className="card-title">Info 2</h5>
                                <p className="card-text">
                                    Details about Info 2
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-footer">
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="btn btn-info btn-block" to='/info2'>Browse</NavLink>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body flex-fill">
                                <h5 className="card-title">Info 3</h5>
                                <p className="card-text">
                                    Details about Info 3
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-footer">
                                <NavLink exact={true} className="btn btn-success btn-block" to='/info3'>View</NavLink>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default home;
```

My approach is quite simple. The application shows the Home component on initial load.

In the Navmenu, I have a link that navigates me to the Login screen.

In the Login screen, I have a login form where I am able to validate the user name and password via an API call.

I have multiple questions as I am still learning, but adding them here altogether as I feel it is all related.

**Questions:**

- In my `NavMenu` component, I want to hide the admin1 and admin2 when on
  initial load, and show it when the login is successful in the Login
  component.
- I want to prevent user from going to the route /admin1 and
  /admin2 unless they are logged in. I am trying to read Protected
  Routes but I am unable to get the hang of it as of yet.
- In my Login screen, after successful login, one of the return value of the API
  call is an API Key I can use for authorized calls. How can I make
  that available such that I can access it from anywhere I perform an
  API call.

I hope I provided enough context on what I am trying to achieve here. I know I need to brush up further my skills on how data communication between React happens.
Update: Been reading about Hooks, but I am unsure how to implement it here. Would I need to convert my JS files to use functional approach rather than class structure (ES6)?

Answer (score 1):

I use redux for checking if use if logged in or not.
So when app start before show anything I check this.
and then I have `privateRoute`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.User.isLogin);
  return (
    <Route
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and define IsAuthenticated component to redirect home page if user is already logged in:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";


function IsAuthenticated({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.User.isLogin)
  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={props =>
        !isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default IsAuthenticated;
```

and define my routes here if user must authenticated to see them:

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {privateRoutes.map(({ path, component: Component }, idx) => (
          <PrivateRoute
            key={idx}
            exact
            path={path}
            component={() => (
              <SideNav>
                <Component />
              </SideNav>
            )}
          />
        ))}

        <IsAuthenticated exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

here I use `SideNav` in my pages, you can use redux state in your `Navbar` component and with checking that you can show or hide whatever you want.
Or you can define two layout for your two types of your pages.

If you don't want to use redux, you can define state in `App.js` and pass it to your component or use react context.

I hope I helped you in your question.

Comment: I have routes which does not need authentication. How do I get the successful authentication data from Login.js to pass up to Layout.js which would then pass down to the Navigation.js component? I'd like to see a solution prior to experimenting with additional react (Redux) implementation. Thanks.

Comment: I see, here is a solution to have two layouts. Use can define two arrays that contain your routes and their components to render two layouts in `Router`. If you want to learn redux you can search and fine great tutorials. If not you can search how to parent and child component pass data between them. If you need more details of it, is another question.

Comment: before I jump in to more complex react stuff, I think I want to understand some basics first, then see how redux would greatly help in this area.

Comment: Pass and change state in every component is what redux does.You can use react context, too.